# how to find file in jar without unjarring it and opening in editor from command line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jar, grep

I have a `foo.jar` which has classes, a lib directory and a META-INT directory.

I am trying to find if `persistence.xml` exists in this jar and open it in `vi` editor.

I tried the following.

```
tar tf foo.jar | grep 'persistence.xml'
```

This shows `META-INF/persistence.xml`.

I am wondering if it is possible to first find the file in jar and then open in vi in single command line if possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually the single command but in one line you can do it as follows:

```
jar=foo.jar; filename=$(unzip -l "$jar" | grep  'persistence.xml' | awk '{print $4}'); test -n "$filename" && vim <(unzip -qc "$jar" "$filename")
```

First you have to set jar file that you will be evaluated and then command is looking for the file name that matches the pattern. Finally if file name is non zero length string, file is being opened in vim editor.